# HTML list not showing bullet point on FIRST list item ONLY

Tags: html, ejs

Title explains pretty much everything. This is a MEAN stack app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>The Test App</title>
</head>

<body>

<ul class="stories"
    <% for (var i=0; i<stories.length; i++) {%>
    <li class "story">
            <span><%= stories[i].title %></span>
            <span><%= stories[i].content %></span>
    </li>
<% } %>
</ul>

<form action="/stories" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="title" name="title">
    <input type="text" placeholder="content" name="content" >
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The output I get is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNfhM.png

I've tried a bit of cursory googling but it seems this isn't something that crops up often. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the closing ">" on the ul tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the closing greater than sign in UL.

```
<ul class="stories">
    <% for (var i=0; i<stories.length; i++) {%>
    <li class "story">
            <span><%= stories[i].title %></span>
            <span><%= stories[i].content %></span>
    </li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, thank you very much. I have no idea how I missed this, or why the page was even displaying correctly.